# How to register a .NET DLL using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have written a class library using Visual Studio 2010 C# to read hardware information of a Computer (e.g. HDD/SSD). I will use this dll to create an installer using InnoSetup to read the hardware info of the target computer. Now my problems is .NET dll cannot be used directly unless it is registered already. I am trying to find a way to register the dll during InitializeSetup in InnoSetup so I can use the functions in the dll. Here is the script I wrote for installer.

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    obj: Variant;
    diskPartitions: Integer;
    va: String;
    ErrorCode: Integer;
    b: Boolean;
begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('SSHardwareChecker.dll');
    RegisterServer(False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SSHardwareChecker.dll'), False);
    obj := CreateOleObject('SSHardwareChecker.SSClass');
    va := obj.GetDiskDriveInformation;
    MsgBox(va, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
    b:=UnregisterServer(False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SSHardwareChecker.dll'), False);
end;
```

The function `RegisterServer` doesn't seem to work.It throws an error which says `RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x4`. I read a lot of articles in the net that says .net dll shoud be registered using regasm. I dont really know how to do this, especially in Inno Setup.

Please help guys.

Answer (score 12):

Though its more than a year, I recently had the same problem and was able to rectify using the below script.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet20}\RegAsm.exe"; Parameters: /codebase YourDLL.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: "Registering Controls..."; Flags: runminimized
```

If the file has be registered at initialize step, we can use one of the Inno setup's support functions.

`function Exec(const Filename, Params, WorkingDir: String; const ShowCmd: Integer; const Wait: TExecWait; var ResultCode: Integer): Boolean;`

More Info can be found in:
[Inno Setup Help](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptautomation)

Comment: Note that this occurs DURING the install and as such, is too late for the DLL to be used during `InitialiseSetup`. Otherwise, it's a valid solution for using the DLL afterwards.

Comment: @Nyerguds What I guess is eventhough if you are working in 3.5 you should have 2.0 also installed with all the core executables inside it. I hope it is also a part of the OS.

Comment: @Venkatesh Kumar I looked it up, and it seems that 3.5 is considered an "update" of 2.0, and, as such, still uses the 2.0 app folder. So `{dotnet20}` works fine for 3.5. Anyway, thanks a lot, this code really helped me out :)

Comment: Note that for language compatibility, you can use the original status message for registering dll files by using something like `{code:StrStatusRegisterFiles}` as `StatusMsg`, and then making that function fetch the original language-dependent installer string from [Messages] with `result := SetupMessage(MsgStatusRegisterFiles);`

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you MUST..

1) make sure that .net 4.0 is installed (not by default on most machines yet)

2) extract and register the DLL (you need to call regasm.exe on the extracted DLL)

This is a lot to do just to "GetDiskDriveInformation" as the very first step of the install.

It is far better to get the information natively in Inno or call a native DLL that doesn't have the prerequisites.