# InnoSetup + MySQL ODBC script = Error Message

Tags: mysql, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have been trying to create an installer using Inno Setup for my vb.net application.

This application has a prerequisite dependency on MySQL ODBC. So, I was thinking if I could check the system if MySQL ODBC is present, and install if not. Well, to be frank, I am a newbie programmer, and I know no hell about debian, which is the script language for InnoSetup.

I was looking for help since some time, through google and stuff, but couldn't find anything other than some examples, and tried coding the script myself.

Here's the script:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{ID goes here}
AppName=DCS
AppVersion=1.0
;AppVerName=DCS 1.0
AppPublisher=Syed
DefaultDirName={pf}\DCS
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName=DCS
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
SetupIconFile=C:\logo.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.vshost.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.vshost.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.application"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.pdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.vshost.application"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.vshost.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\DCS.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[code]
function IsMySQLOdbcInstalled(): boolean;
begin
    If NOT RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver') then
    Result := True
    Else
    Result := False;
end;

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\DCS"; Filename: "{app}\DCS.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\DCS"; Filename: "{app}\DCS.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: {src}\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi; Check: IsMySQLOdbcInstalled()
Filename: "{app}\DCS.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,DCS}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Now, the compile goes fine, and generates a setup.exe executable. When run, the app DCS gets installed, but the MySQL ODBC doesn't and gives an error,

```
Unable to execute file:
'Output path'\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi
Create Process failed; code2.
The system cannot find the file specified. 

OK
```

I thought the output folder needs the mysql-connector-odbc msi installation folder. Just to check, I copied it manually, recompiled and ran setup, only to get the same, but with some change:

```
Unable to execute file:
'Output path'\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi
Create Process failed; code193.
%1 is not a vaild Win32 application. 

OK
```

And also, I wanted the installer to check for the MySQL ODBC driver before any installation proceeds, but here, it does so after the main application install. Can anyone please help me correct this script?

Thanks

Comment: Noo, Debian is a Linux distribution :-) Pascal Script is the language of Inno Setup ;-)

Comment: Anyway, are you sure you want to copy that ODBC installer to your application's folder ? Are you sure you want to copy it to the target machine at all ? There's a way to store it to the temporary folder which is then deleted when the setup is done. To your second question, when exactly do you want to check that the ODBC driver is installed and what do you want to do with such information ?

Comment: whoops! I meant delphi!! not debian LOL!

Comment: No, id not want to copy the ODBC installer to the application folder, but, in the installer itself. So that, when a client wants to install my app, the installer looks for mysql odbc driver before proceeding to install the main app. if odbc is not available, first odbc is installed, and then the main app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `[Run]` section. You're going to execute that MySQL ODBC installer from the `{src}` path. Since you copy your `mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi` installer file to the `{app}` folder, you must run it from the same. Fix your `[Run]` section of the script this way:

```
[Run]
; on the following line, run the executable from the {app} directory instead
; of {src}; the {src} folder is the folder in which the Setup files are located
; since it is not an *.exe file, you must also specify the shellexec flag
Filename: {app}\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi; Check: IsMySQLOdbcInstalled(); Flags: shellexec
Filename: "{app}\DCS.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,DCS}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

***Update:***

To meet your additional requirement, run the ODBC driver installer before the main installation process, I've made the following script example (there are kept only parts relevant to the ODBC driver setup).

Anyway, I guess it might be less annoying if you run the ODBC driver installer in some silent mode with some default setting, so it won't offer wizard to the user if there is some (but that's much wider topic for this question; there will be parameters to control the ODBC driver installer, and those you can pass to the second parameter of the `Exec` function maybe telling the show window flag to be `SW_HIDE` instead of `SW_SHOWNORMAL`, which will keep it hidden from user). Please note, this code is untested:

```
[Setup]
AppName=DCS
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\DCS

[Files]
; keep just the only one flag, "dontcopy"; it will tell the installer to not copy
; this file entry to the target machine, but will be part of the setup binary and
; available for manual extracting by using the ExtractTemporaryFile(s) function
Source: "C:\VS12\Projects\DCS\bin\Debug\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi"; Flags: dontcopy

[Run]
; remove the ODBC driver installer entry from [Run] section since the [Run] section
; is executed after the installation is succesfully finished and your requirement is
; to run it before the installation process
; Filename: {app}\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi; Check: IsMySQLOdbcInstalled()

[Code]
function IsMySQLODBC51Installed: Boolean;
begin
  // the result was inverted in the original code; the original function returned
  // True if the ODBC driver was not installed, False otherwise, and according to
  // the function name it should be vice-versa
  Result := RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver');
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  // if we are right before the main installation starts and ODBC driver is not yet
  // installed, then...
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) and not IsMySQLODBC51Installed then
  begin
    // now extract the ODBC installaer to the Inno Setup's temporary folder
    ExtractTemporaryFile('mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi');
    // and execute the ODBC driver installation (it is necessary to use ShellExec
    // since it is not an *.exe file); if the execution fails, then...
    if not ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.12-win32.msi'), '', '', 
      SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      // show the error message with exit code
      MsgBox('MySQL ODBC Driver setup failed!' + #13#10 + 'Exit code: ' + IntToStr(ResultCode) +
        '; ' + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
      // here you can optionally call Abort to abort the upcoming installation process
      // so if you uncomment the following line, the main installation will not run if
      // the ODBC driver installer execution failed
      // Abort;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: tried this. the first problem is solved i.e not found thing. but the Create Process failed; code193.
%1 is not a vaild Win32 application still remains

Comment: does the [code] segment mean that the functions in the segment will run even if they are not called?

Comment: No, they must be called. Although, the `CurStepChanged` is the [`event function`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) and is fired (called) by the installer. Anyway, to the `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` problem. I missed you're executing *.msi file. So you are missing the shellexec flag. I've made an update to both scripts. Please note the latter is still not tested, I didn't even tried if it's compilable.

Comment: You are awesome dude!. do you think that the key to check mysql odbc is correct? coz i have that installed on my pc, but the installer still brings up the mysql installer wizard.

Comment: That's the question for some MySQL administrator guru. I've worked just once wit MySQL and don't know such details at all. And what is worse, I can't even test it now due to security restrictions set on the computer I'm sitting at. Also, there might be (but it's my guess) two versions of registry keys, one for 32-bit driver and one for 64-bit driver. You will then need to decide, what to do, if the user has e.g. 64-bit driver installed on his machine. But that's more MySQL administration question, than Inno Setup. I can translate the requirement to code, but don't know those requirements :-)

Comment: can you tell me how can i check if a .dll is registered and if not registered, register one? I found that instead of installing the whole odbc, my app works if just the mysql.data.dll is registered or in the same folder as installed. so, i included the .dll in the folder, selected all the files, and included a regserver sharedfile flag along with the code. this gives an error saying that "unable to register the dll/ocs: regsvr32 failed with exit code 0x4" can you please detect where the problem is?

Comment: If that `mysql.data.dll` is a .NET assembly (I assume it is), you're not going to use `regsvr`, but `regasm` tool for registering. An example for inspiration you can find e.g. in [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12384131/960757). If you'll have troubles getting it to work, post a new question, please.